# Could not navigate to fragment using jetpack navigation?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I want to navigate from HomeFragment to DetailFragment 
in RecyclerView item click I am calling DetailFragment and
it is not working ,I see it enters onClickListener but it doesn't go further and it doesn't call DetailFragment

```
viewBinding.assetImage.setOnClickListener {
        val bundle = bundleOf("owner" to "TestUser")
        Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.detail_screen,bundle)
      }
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/home_screen"
    android:name="HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_home_screen_to_detailFragment"
        app:destination="@id/detail_screen" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detail_screen"
    android:name="DetailFragment"
    android:label="DetailFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail">
    <argument
        android:name="owner"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: What exactly happens? Does your app crash? Do you have a logcat output of the error message?

Comment: Why not simple use `findNavController().navigate(R.id.detail_screen, bundle)` instead of `createNavigationOnClickListener`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is solution for you,

```
   val bundle = Bundle()
   bundle.putString("owner", "TestUser")
   if (it.findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.home_screen) {
              it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_home_screen_to_detailFragment, bundle)
   }
```

Comment: Any explanation of your solution is really welcomed

Answer (score 0):

You can use safeArgs to pass data.
[This](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012/lessons/7466f670-3d47-4b60-8f6a-0914ce58f9ad/concepts/e8ecc9a9-b393-4df2-bb5c-72827cc083a4) can help you

1. You go to your navigation xml file
2. Select Fragment to which values are passed.
3. Add attributes

[image: picture][image]

4. Build → Rebuild
5. Then you can use it like this
   `findNavController().navigate(MenuFragmentDirections.Action_menuFragment_to_servisFragment(param))`